# How to convert all Text Row values to column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, window-functions

I have data in all text on the customer and city for each salesman. which looks like

```
Salesman|customer_name|City
Adam| Alex|New york
Adam|Kevin|New york
Adam|Erin|Chicago
Adam|Jim|Los Angeles
Adam|James|New York
Pam|Tod|New York
Pam|Kelly|Chicago
Pam|Rick|Chicago
Lewis|David|Los Angeles
Lewis|Mike|Los Angeles
```

I need to transpose the city column to get the customer name by the city for salesman which should look like in SQL Server. I am not sure if I can do this in Pivot or some other option is there

```
Salesman|New york|Chicago|Los Angeles
Adam|Alex|Erin|Jim
Adam|Kevin|NULL|NULL
Adam|James|NULL|NULL
Pam|Tod|Kelly|NULL
Pam|NULL|Rick|NULL
Lewis|NULL|NULL|David
Lewis|NULL|NULL|Mike
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little tricky, because you want to create several rows for each salesman when they have multiple customers per city. One methdo enumerates the rows in a subquery first, then aggregates:

```
select salesman, 
    max(case when city = 'New York' then customer_name end) new_york,
    max(case when city = 'Chicago' then customer_name end) chicago,
    max(case when city = 'Los Angeles' then customer_name end) los_angeles,
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by salesman, city order by customer_name) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by salesman, rn
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using conditional aggregation

```
select salesmane, 
max(case when city='New york' then customer_name end) as 'New York',
max(case when city='Chicago' then customer_name end) as 'Chicago',
max(case when city='Los Angeles' then customer_name end) as 'Los Angeles'
from t
group by salesman
```

Or you can use pivot -

```
select salesman,piv.* from
t pivot
(max(customer_name) for city in([New York],[Chicago],[Los Angeles])) as piv
```

Comment: I tried 1st query but the values are repeating. I took ID's in the query
salesman|New York|Chicago|Los Angeles
D1|1|2|3
D2|1|2|3
D3|1|2|3
D4|1|NULL|NULL
D5|1|NULL|NULL
D6|1|NULL|NULL
D7|NULL|NULL|3
D8|NULL|NULL|3

Comment: @user14304399 have you put the id column in group by?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot` and `row_number` the following gives expected result,

The trick here is the `row_number` as mentioned by @GMB which is useful either you go with `aggregation` or `pivot`

```
select Salesman
      ,[New York]
      ,[Chicago]
      ,[Los Angeles]
  from
(
select t.salesman
      ,t.customer_name
      ,t.city
      ,row_number() over (partition by salesman,city order by customer_name) rn
  from table1 t
) p
pivot
(
 max(customer_name)
 for city in ([New York]
             ,[Chicago]
             ,[Los Angeles])
) c
order by salesman
```